# Unity 3D 2019: x Position keeps shifting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have made a grid spawner for obstacles on a grid of x -6 to x 6. The objects move -z axis toward the player.

They do not move along the x axis only z. For some reason despite having coded a spawner that places an object every 2 x values it places them at a fraction off each. And gets less each row. So an object placed at x2 the next row at x2 will be at x1.999987 and then x1.998 and so on.

The x value of each object should only be one of following (-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6)

This is causing me an issue because I need to also be able to select two objects and swap them. This requires my script to scan the board for active objects and find x valuesof the objects and swap over. If the x values are not solid whole numbers it wont detect any other objects.

Thank you in advance for any advice :)

[image]

Spawn code:

```
void SpawnGrid()
{

    for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < gridZ; z++)
        {
            float x1 = Mathf.Round(x * gridSpacingOffset);
            float z1 = Mathf.Round(z * gridSpacingOffset);
            Debug.Log("x1: " + x1);
            Debug.Log("x2: " + z1);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(x1, 0, z1) + gridOrigin;
            PickAndSpawn(spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}

void PickAndSpawn(Vector3 positionToSpawn, Quaternion rotationToSpawn)
    {
        // Pick a "random" number between 0 and the length of the obstacle array
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, itemsToPickFrom.Length);

        Debug.Log("RandomIndex is: " + randomIndex);

        // Declare obstacle types
        obj = ObjectPooler.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject("Obstacle_Type_1");
        obj1 = ObjectPooler.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject("Obstacle_Type_2");
        obj2 = ObjectPooler.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject("Obstacle_Type_3");
        obj3 = ObjectPooler.SharedInstance.GetPooledObject("Obstacle_Type_4");

        // Add obstacles to an array
        objectTypes[0] = obj;
        objectTypes[1] = obj1;
        objectTypes[2] = obj2;
        objectTypes[3] = obj3;

        // Spawn the obstacle chosen by the random index number
        if (objectTypes[randomIndex] == null)
            return;
        objectTypes[randomIndex].transform.position = positionToSpawn;
        objectTypes[randomIndex].transform.rotation = rotationToSpawn;
        ontheBoard.Add(objectTypes[randomIndex]);
        objectTypes[randomIndex].SetActive(true);

    }
```

Object movement code:

void Start()
    {

```
    currentPos = transform.position;

}

void Update()
{

    destinationPos = currentPos;
    destinationPos.z = destinationPos.z - moveStep;
    currentPos = transform.position;

}

void FixedUpdate()
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destinationPos, moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    }
```

Swap Code:

```
private void swapIt(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2)
    {
        if (swap != true)
        {

            startPos = pos1;
            endPos = pos2;
            archMidPos = startPos + (endPos - startPos) / 2 + Vector3.up * archHeight;
            swap = true;

        }

    }

void Update()
    {

        moveSpeed = obj1.GetComponent<Cube_Control>().moveSpeed;
        moveStep = obj1.GetComponent<Cube_Control>().moveStep;

        destinationPosObj1 = currentPosObj1;
        destinationPosObj1.z = destinationPosObj1.z - moveStep;
        currentPosObj1 = obj1.transform.position;

        destinationPosObj2 = currentPosObj2;
        destinationPosObj2.z = destinationPosObj2.z - moveStep;
        currentPosObj2 = obj2.transform.position;

        // For testing press SPACEBAR to swap objects

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            /*
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lvlManager.GetComponent<Grid_Spawn>().ontheBoard.Count);

            obj1 = lvlManager.GetComponent<Grid_Spawn>().ontheBoard[randomIndex];

            foreach (GameObject ob in lvlManager.GetComponent<Grid_Spawn>().ontheBoard)
            {
                if (ob.transform.position.x == (obj1.transform.position.x + 4))
                {
                    obj2 = ob;
                    swapIt(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position);
                }
                else { Debug.Log("No object nearby to swap"); }
            }*/

            swapIt(obj1.transform.position, obj2.transform.position);

        }        

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //loat cnt = gs.ontheBoard.Count;
        //Debug.Log("ontheboard count: " + cnt);

        if (swap == true)
        {

            if (count < 1.0f)
            {

                count += 1.0f * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

                // Lerp the primary object to the new position in an arching motion

                Vector3 archMidPosObj1 = archMidPos;
                Vector3 endPosObj1 = endPos;

                archMidPosObj1.z = archMidPosObj1.z - moveStep;
                endPosObj1.z = endPosObj1.z - moveStep;

                Vector3 m1 = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, archMidPosObj1, count);
                Vector3 m2 = Vector3.Lerp(archMidPosObj1, endPosObj1, count);

                // Move Object 1

                obj1.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(m1, m2, count);

                // Calculate the inverse arch (-Y) and Lerp the secondary object in a negative arching motion

                float midposY = archMidPos.y - (archMidPos.y * 2);
                Vector3 archMidPosReverse = archMidPos;
                archMidPosReverse.y = midposY;

                Vector3 obj2StartPos = startPos;
                archMidPosReverse.z = archMidPosReverse.z - moveStep;
                obj2StartPos.z = obj2StartPos.z - moveStep;

                Vector3 m3 = Vector3.Lerp(endPos, archMidPosReverse, count);
                Vector3 m4 = Vector3.Lerp(archMidPosReverse, obj2StartPos, count);

                // Move Object 2

                obj2.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(m3, m4, count);
                // Reset swap boolean and count once object has swapped places

                if (obj1.transform.position.x == endPos.x)
                {

                    swap = false;
                    count = 0;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 04/04/2020:

Ok so I have noticed that the x value shifts due to multiplying by fixedDeltaTime in FixedUpdate()

If you attach below script to an object on x round number and press play it will move along the z axis, the x will shift from the round number to long decimal float.

If you comment out the line in FixedUpdate (transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destinationPos, moveStep * Time.fixedDeltaTime);) and remove comment slashes from statement below now the object stays on the whole x number, however the speed along z axis is no longer constant and loses sync each frame with other objects on same z axis moving at same pace..

Settings I currently user are:

- moveSpeed: 4
- moveStep: 2.5
- Mass: 1
- Drag/Angular Drag: None
- Use Gravity: No
- isKinematic: Yes
- Interpolate: None
- Collision: Continuous Speculative
- Constraints: None

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube_Control : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float moveSpeed;
    public float moveStep;
    public Vector3 currentPos;
    public Vector3 destinationPos;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        currentPos = transform.position;
        currentPos.x = Mathf.Round(currentPos.x);
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    void Update()
    {

        destinationPos = currentPos;
        destinationPos.z = destinationPos.z - moveStep;
        destinationPos.x = Mathf.Round(destinationPos.x);
        currentPos = transform.position;
        currentPos.x = Mathf.Round(currentPos.x);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destinationPos, moveStep * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destinationPos, moveStep);


    }

    public void setObstacleSpeed(float speed)
    {
        moveSpeed = speed;
    }

    public void setObstacleMoveStep(float step)
    {
        moveStep = step;
    }

    private void Destroy(GameObject obj)
    {
        obj.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        Debug.Log("Ow! I Feel Triggerd " + other);

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "WallOfDoom")
        {
            Debug.Log("I hit the WALL OF DOOOOOOMMM!");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Plyr_Bullet")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ow! I Feel Triggerd " + collision);

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "WallOfDoom")
        {
            Debug.Log("I hit the WALL OF DOOOOOOMMM!");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your x value still as you want it during `Debug.Log("x1: " + x1);`? If so, at what point does the position x start carrying the wrong value?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen yes it is :) Which is why I am so confused. It seems absolutely fine right up until spawning, I pause the game when the row spawns and all are off by a few decimal places. Its very rare that one is placed dead on the x value it should be. I did cheat by using Mathf.Round in update to constantly correct the x position but this causes other problems..not really a fix.

Comment: Could you post a full set of x numbers? Note tiny float variations can happen in Unity but as far as I know not really to the extent I'm seeing in your second example (1.998f instead of 2f).

Comment: @PhilippLenssen sure, thanks, Row 1: x= -5.998415, -3.998936, -1.999466, 0, 1.999466, 3.998936, 5.998415 | Row 2: x= -5.997673, -3.998437, -1.999215, 0, 1.999215, 3.998437, 5.997673 | Row 3: x= -5.992811, -3.995169, -1.997573, 0 , 1.997573, 3.995169, 5.992811  **Side note, I have also checked that the collision boxes do not touch and they don't. Also x is constant it does not vary throughout their journey along z axis**

Comment: Ok thanks. So it looks like the offset is growing in each step as it gets further away from zero at roughly (but not exactly) 0.000785f steps. If you have the project on Github, I can take another look by loading it up here, but otherwise it's difficult to debug from afar.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Ok I will put together a version for github if need be. I did just discover that if I remove Time.fixedDeltaTime from the movement script (transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destinationPos, moveStep * Time.fixedDeltaTime); suddenly they all are perfect on x axis! But now they fly across the screen and become out of synch on the z axis but its a clue! Cheers :)

Comment: @PhilippLenssen added script to my original post at bottom